# Adjusting image (bootstrap 5 Carousel)

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I need your assistance in positioning the images in the Carousel.
I am still new in using the bootstrap and We developing in general.

```css
.carousel-inner {
    height: 500px;
}
.carousel-inner .carousel-item { 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
                aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="picture">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="picture">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="picture">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: First things first, you had a stray closing `</button>` tag at the end of your HTML which I removed in my edit

Comment: You forgot to mention how you would like your images positioned. What is the end goal and what is not working now?